# Change mysql version in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp

I'm running wamp 3.1.0 WITH mysql 5.5.57 (downgraded from 5.7.19), yet phpmyadmin is still using 5.7.19, what do I need to do for phpmyadmin to use mysql 5.5.57?

Comment: Did you use the WAMPServer ADDON to install MySQL 5.5.57? Then did you use the WAMPServer menus to switch MySQL version?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so it seems to have been a glitch. Wamp was showing 5.5 but still running 5.7 even after many restarts. It took several tries switching between mysql versions for it to actually change.

Comment: Makes me think of the Dr. Seuss book.  "WAMP is good. WAMP is fun. Tomorrow is another one."

Answer (score 1):

maybe you should ask this in superuser.com...

or just try in this order:

**first of all backup your data!**

1 - download the version of mysql that you want to install.

2 - Copy / Paste it in your folder C:\wamp\bin\mysql

3 - Close and run Wamp server again

4 - Left click the Wamp icon in your taskbar then Mysql > Version > 'select your version'

here is also old versions of [wampserver:](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/)

Answer (score 1):

The fix for this problem for me was to change my config.inc.php file to use mysql host localhost instead of 172.0.0.1 under:

```
if($wampConf['SupportMySQL'] == 'on') {
set:
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
```

Answer (score 0):

> what do I need to do for phpmyadmin to use mysql 5.5.57?

Connect to a MySQL server running that version.  `phpmyadmin` has no control over the version of server you use with it.

It seems likely you're not connecting to the MySQL server you think you're connecting to.

Comment: Right... I have wamp 5.5.57 selected in wamp, but you are correct, mysql 5.7.19 is running. I have restarted all services without luck